# How to draw a shuffled staircase in PyGame

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, data-visualization

So I decided to make an array visualizer in pygame, and I decided to program the basic visualizer.

Here is the code which is arranging the rectangles, but it doesn't work:

```
#other code

list = list(range(129))
random.shuffle(list)

#other code

ended = False
while not ended:    
    
    #other code
    
    for i in range(len(list)):

        x1 = i*15
        y1 = 1080-list[i]*8

        x2 = 15+i*15
        y2 = 1080

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is [expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ISlO.png) vs [reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDPQe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.Rect` params are `(left, top, width, height)`, not `(left, top, right, bottom)`: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect

Try something like:

```
    for i in range(len(list)):

        x1 = i*15
        y1 = 1080-list[i]*8

        x2 = 15
        y2 = list[i]*8
```

`x2` should be the width of your rect and `y2` its height.

Welcome to StackOverflow btw :)

Comment: that's what I was doing wrong, thank you!